# Write a dictionary to a csv file in tables. It keeps showing "String indices must be integers"

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a table in csv file with a header ['Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR']

I have looked the "String indices must be integers" up online

Following the instructions, Python still keeps outputting the same type error

This is really upsetting

Does anyone know how to solve?

```
import csv

dict_data = {'ac': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 2}, 'ahmed.miller': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 4}, 'blossom': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 6}, 'bpacheco': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 2}, 'breee': {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 5}, 'britanni': {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 1}, 'enim.non': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'flavia': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 5}, 'jackowens': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 4}, 'kirknixon': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 1}, 'mai.hendrix': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 3}, 'mcintosh': {'INFO': 4, 'ERROR': 3}, 'mdouglas': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'montanap': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 4}, 'noel': {'INFO': 6, 'ERROR': 3}, 'nonummy': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'oren': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 7}, 'rr.robinson': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 1}, 'sri': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 2}, 'xlg': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 4}}

with open("testinggg.csv", 'w') as output:
fields = ['Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields)
writer.writeheader()
for m in dict_data:
  print(m)
  writer.writerow({'Username': str(m[0]), 'INFO': str(m[1]['error']), 'ERROR': str(m[1]['info'])})
```

Python keeps showing this no matter how hard I try:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `m` is a string. You index it with an integer, yielding a string, which you then index using the string `"error"`, which raises an error because you are indexing the string with a string.

Comment: @iteratedwalls Thats the solution I learnt from this link: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers/ It says "We can access items in our dictionary using a string. This is because dictionary keys can be strings."

Comment: @koknoeyuki for a longer explanation, check out the accepted answer below. In future, try to debug these issues before immediately coming to stackoverflow - the learning experience will help you far more than immediately getting others to do it for you does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for m in dict_data` is only iterating the keys of the dict, which are strings. And you should see that with your `print(m)` statements:

```
ac
ahmed.miller
blossom
bpacheco
breee
...
```

The statement `m[0]` will give you just the first letter, like 'a' in 'ac'.  The statement `m[1]['error']` is the source of your error; you're treating the second letter, 'c' in 'ac', like it's a dict.

To get your username, the key, and INFO/ERROR, the values, use the items() iterator:

```py
for k, v in dict_data.items():
    writer.writerow({'Username': k, 'INFO': v['INFO'], 'ERROR': v['ERROR']})
```

You've also got errors in how you're trying to access the sub-dicts:

- the INFO/ERROR keys are capitalized
- you swapped info/error in your example

The above code fixes both of those issues.

Comment: just one question--- may I ask why did you use writerow but not writerows? and when I tried to write writerows it shows errors: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'" I dont really get it

Comment: @Kokonoeyuki writerows (plural) expects a list of individual row objects (dicts in your case); writerow only expects a single row object (dict). So, when you call writerows with a singular row, things break down. I'm guessing it tries to iterate your dict, which give it just the keys (as a string); thinking it has a complete dict it then calls the keys() method, but because it's only a string, you get that error.

Comment: @Kokonoeyuki Also, have you checked out the documentation for the csv module, and **all** the examples? <https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter> Check back with that often if you're just getting started with the csv module... I've been using it for years, and that's still my #1 go-to when I'm trying to answer my own CSV-related questions, or questions here on SO.

Comment: I thought writerow is to write all lines into one single row in csv format, and writerows is to write each row separately in csv format...okay I will check that out, thanks :))